# Serial Port on Winforms

Tags: c#

I was wondering why my serial port is not recieving when i am using the winform application, but on the  console application i used the same code it's working fine.

**Note: I did put a breakpoint on the dataReceive event but it's not receiving any events. It's receiving only once , when the screen is loaded,but after that never recieve an events**

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

SerialPort serRec = null;

SerialPort ser = null;

private void SetText(string text)
    {
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        serRec = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        serRec.Open();

        serRec.DataReceived += (sendexr, se) =>
        {
            var r = serRec.ReadLine();
            SetText(r);
        };
        serRec.ReadTimeout = 1000;

        ser = new SerialPort("COM6", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        ser.Open();
        while (true)
        {
            ser.WriteTimeout = 1000;
            ser.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are doing a `while(true) within the click event. Thus you are blocking the UI forever (cause the while loop doesn't have any break or return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess, however my spidey senses tells me its most likely a UI threading issue,

The [`SerialPort.DataReceived`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/da-dk/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event is raised on a separate thread. If you need to asynchronously handle the receipt of data and update the UI you will need to marshal back to the UI thread.

From MSDN

> The `DataReceived` event is raised on a secondary thread when data is
>   received from the `SerialPort` object. Because this event is raised on a
>   secondary thread, and not the main thread, **attempting to modify some
>   elements in the main thread, such as UI elements, could raise a
>   threading exception**. If it is necessary to modify elements in the main
>   Form or Control, post change requests back using Invoke...

**Exmaple**

```
private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    var port = (SerialPort)sender;
    string data = port.ReadExisting();

    UpdateGui(data);
}

private void UpdateGui(string data) {
    if (this.InvokeRequired) {
        this.Invoke(new Action( d => UpdateGui(d) ));
        return;
    }

    this.txtBox1.Text = data;
}
```

**Note** : The reason this probably didn't make a difference in a console app is because you can write to the console on any thread.

---

[Control.InvokeRequired Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets a value indicating whether the caller must call an invoke method
>   when making method calls to the control because the caller is on a
>   different thread than the one the control was created on.

[Control.Invoke Method (Delegate)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's
>   underlying window handle.

---

## Update

**Comment from MickyD**

> Best to use `BeginInvoke` rather than `Invoke`, latter can lead to
>   deadlocks

[Control.BeginInvoke Method (Delegate)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread that the
>   control's underlying handle was created on.

Comment: Best to use `BeginInvoke` rather than `Invoke`, latter can lead to deadlocks

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about this also, but don't know where to start, i will give it a shot thank you for the heads up

Comment: I forgot to mention, the event's fired once only when i click the button,but after that it doesn't recieve any events...

Comment: @PongPagong that while loop is the problem

Comment: It's not the while loop , i tried creating another form for the while loop it's still not working.

Comment: @PongPagong im glad you figured it out

Comment: another question,what do you suggest,if i am reading line by line textfile?

Comment: @PongPagong just File.ReadAllLines if its not super huge